# Collect info from multiple lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to extract certain info from multiple lines (5 lines every transaction) and make the output as csv file. These lines are coming from a maillog wherein every transaction has its own transaction id. Here's one sample transaction:

```
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 sm-mta[14107]: tAGGFJla014107: from=<sender@domain>, size=2447, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201511161615.tAGGFJla014107@server01>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, tls_verify=NONE, auth=NONE, relay=[100.24.134.19]
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 flow-control[6033]: tAGGFJla014107 accepted
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 MM: [Jilter Processor 21 - Async Jilter Worker 9 - 127.0.0.1:51698-tAGGFJla014107] INFO  user.log  - virus.McAfee: CLEAN - Declaration for Shared Parental Leave Allocation System
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 MM: [Jilter Processor 21 - Async Jilter Worker 9 - 127.0.0.1:51698-tAGGFJla014107] INFO  user.log  - mtaqid=tAGGFJla014107, msgid=<201511161615.tAGGFJla014107@server01>, from=<sender@domain>, size=2488, to=<recipient@domain>, relay=[100.24.134.19], disposition=Deliver
Nov 17 00:15:20 server01 sm-mta[14240]: tAGGFJla014107: to=<recipient@domain>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=smtp, pri=122447, relay=relayserver.domain. [100.91.20.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (tAGGFJlR021747 Message accepted for delivery)
```

What I tried is, I made these 5 lines into 1 line and used awk to parse each column - unfortunately, the column count is not uniform.

I'm looking into getting the date/time (line 1, columns 1-3), sender, recipient, and subject (line 3, words after "CLEAN -" to the end of line)

Preferably sed or awk in bash.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your expect output?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: `file`is your file.
The script initializes `id` and `block` to empty strings. At first run `id` takes the value of field nr. 7. After that all lines are added to `block` until a line doesn't match `id`. At that point `block` and `id` are reinitialized.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{id="";block=""} {if (id=="") id=$6; else {if ($0~id) block= block $0; else {print block;block=$0;id=$6}}}' file
```

Then you're going to have to process each line of the output.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this. Here is one example calling a simple script and passing the log filename as the first argument. It will parse the requested data and save the data separated into individual variables. It simply prints the results at the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -r "$1" ] || {  ## validate input file readable
    printf "error: invalid argument, file not readable '%s'\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

while read -r line; do

    ## set date from line containing from/sender
    if grep -q -o 'from=<' <<<"$line" &>/dev/null; then
        dt=$(cut -c -15 <<<"$line")
        from=$(grep -o 'from=<[a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]*>' <<<"$line")
        sender=${from##*<}
        sender=${sender%>*}
    fi
    ## search each line for CLEAN
    if grep -q -o 'CLEAN.*$' <<<"$line" &>/dev/null; then
        subject=$(grep -o 'CLEAN.*$' <<<"$line")
        subject="${subject#*CLEAN - }"
    fi
    ## search line for to
    if grep -q -o 'to=<' <<<"$line" &>/dev/null; then
        to=$(grep -o 'to=<[a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9]*>' <<<"$line")
        to=${to##*<}
        to=${to%>*}
    fi

done < "$1"

printf " date   : %s\n from   : %s\n to     : %s\n subject: \"%s\"\n" \
"$dt" "$sender" "$to" "$subject"
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/mail.log
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 sm-mta[14107]: tAGGFJla014107: from=<sender@domain>, size=2447, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201511161615.tAGGFJla014107@server01>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, tls_verify=NONE, auth=NONE, relay=[100.24.134.19]
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 flow-control[6033]: tAGGFJla014107 accepted
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 MM: [Jilter Processor 21 - Async Jilter Worker 9 - 127.0.0.1:51698-tAGGFJla014107] INFO  user.log  - virus.McAfee: CLEAN - Declaration for Shared Parental Leave Allocation System
Nov 17 00:15:19 server01 MM: [Jilter Processor 21 - Async Jilter Worker 9 - 127.0.0.1:51698-tAGGFJla014107] INFO  user.log  - mtaqid=tAGGFJla014107, msgid=<201511161615.tAGGFJla014107@server01>, from=<sender@domain>, size=2488, to=<recipient@domain>, relay=[100.24.134.19], disposition=Deliver
Nov 17 00:15:20 server01 sm-mta[14240]: tAGGFJla014107: to=<recipient@domain>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=smtp, pri=122447, relay=relayserver.domain. [100.91.20.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (tAGGFJlR021747 Message accepted for delivery)
```

**Output**

```
$ bash parsemail.sh dat/mail.log
 date   : Nov 17 00:15:19
 from   : sender@domain
 to     : recipient@domain
 subject: "Declaration for Shared Parental Leave Allocation System"
```

**Note:** if your *from/sender* is not always going to be in the first line, you can simply move those lines out from under the test clause. Let me know if you have any questions.